# How to control text in edittext after key is pressed?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to control the text input via `EdiText` in Android Studio Java so that for example:

When an user presses '1', "10" appeares in `EdiText`

When an user presses 'R' or there's a certain number of characters on some other `EdiText` nothing happens (no text is added to `EdiText`) etc.

Probably it's possible to do with `TextWatcher`, but I'd also like the rules not to work when using `Edittext.setText()`.

Comment: share code you try

Comment: can't understand your question, please describe more

Answer (score 4):

Its can not done by `TextWatcher` but its done by `InputFilter` See:

```
private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if (source != null && yourString.contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Use this filter in `EditText` Like:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

So, you can control whenever user input new character in `EditText`.